# Exactly what is a symbol reference in an object file?

Tags: linker, ld, elf

I am reading computer systems from a programmers' perspective, the chapter about linking. It explains how linking works in linux x86-64 using the program ld. The authors claim, that in order to build an executable file from relocatable object files, the linker does 2 things: symbol resolution and relocation. This is their brief overview of what symbol resolution is:

> Object files define and reference symbols, where each symbol corresponds to a function, a global variable, or a static variable (i.e., any C variable declared with the static attribute). The purpose of symbol resolution is to associate each symbol reference with exactly one symbol definition.

But they don't clarify what is meant by symbol reference, even when they begin describing symbol resolution in depth. So how exactly are symbols referenced in relocatable object files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the following source:

```
static int foo() { return 42; }
static int bar() { return foo() + 1; }

extern int baz();

int main()
{
  return foo() + bar() + baz();
}
```

After `gcc -c foo.c`, the output from `objdump -d foo.o` on x86_64 Linux is:

```
foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%eax
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq

000000000000000b <bar>:
   b:   55                      push   %rbp
   c:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  14:   e8 e7 ff ff ff          callq  0 <foo>
  19:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  1c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  1d:   c3                      retq

000000000000001e <main>:
  1e:   55                      push   %rbp
  1f:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  22:   53                      push   %rbx
  23:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  27:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  2c:   e8 cf ff ff ff          callq  0 <foo>
  31:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
  33:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  38:   e8 ce ff ff ff          callq  b <bar>
  3d:   01 c3                   add    %eax,%ebx
  3f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  44:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  49 <main+0x2b>
  49:   01 d8                   add    %ebx,%eax
  4b:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4f:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  50:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  51:   c3                      retq
```

There are a few things to note here:

1. Notice how `bar` calls `foo` at address `0`?
   How does `objdump` know that it's `foo` that's being called?
   And can it really be at address 0? (Most modern systems map zero page of virtual memory with `PROT_NONE`, so no read or write access can happen there.)
2. Notice how call to `baz` from `main` is different from calls to `foo` and `bar`? The compiler knows where `foo` and `bar` are relative to the call instruction itself, but it has no idea where `baz` will be.

So, given above info, how can the linker turn this into something sensible? It can't: there is not enough info here.

In order for the linker to be able to link reference to `baz` (which we don't yet see) into a call to `baz`, it needs additional info. On ELF systems, that additional info is written into a special section `.rela.text` here, which contains:

```
$ readelf -Wr foo.o

Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x5d0 contains 1 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
0000000000000045  0000000b00000002 R_X86_64_PC32          0000000000000000 baz - 4
```

*That* is the "reference" that the book talks about, but doesn't define. It tells the linker: if you can find a definition of `baz` (in some other object), take its address, and put it (actually, `&baz - 4` because the `CALL` instruction is relative to the *next* instruction after the `CALL`) into bytes [45-48] of `.text` section of `foo.o`.

And if there is no such definition? The linker will produce an error:

```
$ gcc foo.o
foo.o: In function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `baz'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Finally, getting to point 1 above: can the `foo` really be at address 0?

No, but the `CALL` instruction at address `0x14` doesn't actually say `CALL 0`. It says "call routine at address of the next instruction after the call, minus 25". If that call instruction in the final binary ends up at address `0x400501`, then the target of that call will be `0x4004ed`, which is where `foo` will end up (the distance between `foo` and the `CALL` will not change when the linker relocates `.text` section of `foo.o` to a different address (linker relaxation notwithstanding; but that's a complicated topic for another day).

Comment: So the .rela.text table contains entries which ,roughly speaking, contain information about which parts of text need to be modified when linking and a symbol reference at that location (which is an index into the symbol table, thats what I understand Symbol's Value to mean above). Is this correct?

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Roughly correct. The symbol value is `0` (because the symbol is undefined), the symbol table index is encoded in the `Info` field.

Answer (score 4):

Employed Russian's answer is good, but there's a short answer, too: a symbol reference is any time you use a variable (or function name).  A symbol definition creates a variable (or function name).

So a symbol definition would be `int bar;` (so long as it's global) or `int foo() { ... }`. A symbol reference would then be `foo(bar)` (two references: `foo` and `bar`).